# java.lang.ClassCastException: In Web-DriverWait when using PageFactory with POM

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am using Page factory model in selenium to initialise the web elements.
I have wait operations in my code, while passing the web element to my wait operations, it throws "ClassCastException".
I am not able to find solution, any leads will be great. Please suggest me some ways to cast the Page factory' object to WebElement' object.

`@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//*[@id='menu-posts']/div[3]/div/ul/li[3]/a")
       public WebElement categories;`

```
    public void menus() {
            try {
                loginTest();
                menuPosts.click();
                waitClick((WebElement) categories);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                driver.quit();
            }
        }
    public void waitClick(WebElement element) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By) element));
        element.click();
    }


**Exception trace:**

    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7 cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.By
        at com.pageObject.categories.waitClick(categories.java:75)
        at com.pageObject.categories.menus(categories.java:54)
        at SeleniumFramework.com.framework.AppTest.viewPost(AppTest.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

Comment: What is element ?

Comment: You need to change  `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By) element));` to  `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting the variable `categories` to a `WebElement` when it's already a `WebElement`.

Change this line

```
waitClick((WebElement) categories);
```

to this

```
waitClick(categories);
```

and it should get rid of the exception.

Another problem you are going to run into is that your `waitClick()` function is casting a `WebElement` into a `By`. You don't need the cast there. Better yet, you should be waiting for the element to be clickable before you click it. I would rewrite it like the below.

```
public void waitClick(WebElement element)
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
}
```

Further more, the creator of Selenium, Simon Stewart, [recommends not using Page Factory](https://youtu.be/gyfUpOysIF8?t=27m24s). I would instead store locators at the top of the class and then use them, as needed. I would rewrite the whole thing as below.

```
public By categoriesLocator = By.xpath("//*[@id='menu-posts']/div[3]/div/ul/li[3]/a");

public void menus()
{
    try
    {
        loginTest();
        menuPosts.click(); // why aren't you using waitClick() here?
        waitClick(categoriesLocator);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}

public void waitClick(By locator)
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
}
```