# Unable to click on element passed from factory method

Tags: java, selenium, testing, appium, pageobjects

Hi i am trying to click on an element which location is defined using PageFactory.But it is showing NullPointerException.

**Locator class:**

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@content-desc = 'Navigate up']")
public By backButton;
```

**PageObject class:**

```
public AskPage()
{
   PageFactory.initElements(driver, AskLocator.class);
}

public void backButtonClick()
{
   if(backButtondisplayed())
      commonactions.clickElement(driver, askLocator.backButton);
}
```

Am i doing anything wrong?

Note: I have not added classes. I have just added click method and locator for backbutton in page factory class. i have tried changing return type to WebElemment and it works fine. Now i am wondering can i send "By" object from factory class?

Comment: have you initialize the driver instance ?

Comment: You should spend some time reading the docs on `PageFactory`. You aren't using it correctly. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @NarendraRajput When i change the return type to WebElement in factory class then element is coming proper but when i am trying to return By object it becomes null. I wanted to get By object as all the methods i have written takes By object as input. Is it possible to send By Object from Factory class?

Comment: @JeffC this question is different from question suggested by you.

Comment: No, it's actually not. You are getting a null pointer exception which is what that question addresses... what they are and how to find and fix them. You need to read it carefully and debug your application to learn where the issue is and to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

You are initialising 'this' class which means you are initialisinf AskPage.class.

`PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);`

But there is no need to initialise 'AskPage', as you are not locating any web elements.

So the solution is:

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, askLocator.class:);
```

It will do the magic for you now.

Make the web element as static in askLocator.class or create object and access the web element.

Comment: Hey thanks. This was one of the mistakes. I corrected this but still element is coming null from factory class.

Comment: When i change the return type to WebElement in factory class then element is coming proper but when i am trying to return By object it becomes null. I wanted to get By object as all the methods i have written takes By object as input. Is it possible to send By Object from Factory class?

Comment: post one of your methods which takes` By` as input.

Comment: public static void waitUntilElementIsVisible(WebDriver driver, By element)
 {
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
  
  
 }

Comment: for example above method takes By as input. It does not work when i pass WebElement to it.

Comment: Pleas refer the below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314243/java-lang-classcastexception-in-web-driverwait-when-using-pagefactory-with-pom?noredirect=1#comment73696067_43314243